# Adding cordova.js prevents geolocation (or any other) callback

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I created an Ionic project to convert an existing AngularJS webapp to a hybrid app. Works perfectly.

I added `cordova-plugin-geolocation` to get the geolocation working, which did, but I saw that the `cordova.plugins.diagnostic` has better support, so I added that. However, to get that working I had to add to index.html `<script src="cordova.js"></script>` which wasn't in before.

So, I now try to get the location authorization when the app loads as follows:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins) {
        console.log('Cordova plugins ready');
        if (window.cordova.plugins.diagnostic) {
            console.log('Diagnostic plugin ready');
            window.cordova.plugins.diagnostic.getLocationAuthorizationStatus(evaluateGeolocationAuthorizationStatus, onGeolocationAuthorizationError);
        }
    }
});
```

When looking in the console I do see `Diagnostic plugin ready`, but nothing happens. When I run in the  chrome console `window.cordova.plugins.diagnostic.getLocationAuthorizationStatus(function(status) {console.log('status: ' + status)}, function(error) {console.log (error)});` I get `undefined`.

When I try the classical `window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, options)` I also get `undefined`.

When I remove `<script src="cordova.js"></script>` I don't have access to `window.cordova`, but now the callback of `window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`works again.

So, in short: adding `<script src="cordova.js"></script>` prevents these callbacks.

I already removed and added again the Android platform, but all stays the same. Can anyone help?

```
ionic 5.2.2
cordova 9.0.0
cordova-android 8.1.0
```

my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "x",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "x",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/v1-toolkit": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.5.6",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^3.7.0",
    "gulp-exec": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-xml-transformer": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
      "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `cordova-plugin-diagnostic` plugin??

Comment: The issue with the geolocation plugin is that when the user gets the permission dialog to allow or disallow the `window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` callback goes directly into error before the user even presses. When the user allows (in my case) he would need to press again the "locate me" button for kit to work. It's described on the internet as kind of default behaviour. With `cordova.plugins.diagnostic` the call back should wait for the user to press allow or disallow + the diagnistic plugin had other features as well I would like to use.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and for me, the reason was quite difficult to track down.
Bascially the .js plugin was not able to talk with the host android plugin and the only error/warning message I was able to find was a cryptic `Ignoring {action} from previous page load`. But in the end, the root cause, in my case, was the fact that I've changed the `Hostname`'s default value from `localhost` to my custom domain (e.g. `fancy-app.com`). And [according to the ionic webview plugin documentation](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/blob/master/README.md):

> **Hostname**
>
> Default value is `localhost`.
>
> Example `ionic://app` on iOS, `http://app` on Android.
>
> If you change it, you'll need to add a new **allow-navigation** entry in the config.xml for the configured url (i.e  if Hostname is set to app). This is only needed for the Android url when using http://, https:// or a custom scheme. **All ionic:// urls are whitelisted by the plugin.**

That explained also why the plugin worked on iOS (where by default the scheme is `ionic://` but not on Adroid).
As as soon as I added `<allow-navigation href="http://app/*"/>` in my `config.xml` file it worked fine.